# iterate over rows through specific values in a row?

Tags: python

So my csv file has 2 values that I want to skip over the rows containing it. These are "-" and "NA". I'm not using a pandas module because I want to write the updated information into a new csv file.

```py
for row in open("modified_data.csv"):
  values = row.strip().split(',')
  prices = values[1:]
  for price in prices:
    if "-" in price:
      continue
    if "NA" in price:
      continue
  else:
    pass
  print(values)
```

So I'm just trying to remove the rows that have "NA" and "-" by skipping through them and later printing out values to represent the first index too since the condition loop is focus on [1:]. But the print(values) at the end just prints the original data. Any reason why? I also tried pass on the condition, but same results.

Comment: nothing you do after initially settings `values` changes the values array in any way

Comment: Not even writing it into a new csv file? But I'm not changing the values, I just want to skip over some of them if they meet a condition

Comment: Replace `continue` to `break` and try to use `else` suite of `for`. It is executed only if the `for` loop was never broken.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by else suite of for? And where should I use it?

Comment: @NLT I posted an answer of this post.

Answer (score 1):

Does it work for you?

```py
with open('modified_data.csv') as f:
    for row in f.readlines():
        values = row.strip().split(',')
        prices = values[1:]
        for price in prices:
            if '-' in price or 'NA' in price:
                break
        else:
            print(values)
```

#### Explanation:

The `continue` statement can't skip outer loop. It only skips current loop.

The `else` suite of `for` statement is only executed if the `for` loop was ended without `break`. So you should use `break` and `else` suite.

And I modified the way to open file. `with` statement will guarantee  to close the file.

#### Example of output:

For csv file

```
1,2,3,4,5
2,6,7,8,9
3,30,40,-
4,20,50,60
5,NA,10,90
6,9,9,0
```

output will be

```py
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
['2', '6', '7', '8', '9']
['4', '20', '50', '60']
['6', '9', '9', '0']
```

Answer (score -1):

You printed the original data because you havn't changed `values` no matter how you manipulate `prices` `values` will have the original data.